# Display Python Output on Login Screen

Tags: python, login, startup, startup-applications

I am trying to **display the output of a python file on the login screen** of Ubuntu 22.04. For example, say I had a file *startup.py* that simply prints my IP address. I would like to display that printed output on the login screen so that the user does not have to log in to see their IP address.

My guess is that I have to create a bash script that runs a python3 command. Then, open Ubuntu's "Startup Applications" app and create a new startup application that runs the created bash script.

Not sure how to display it on the login screen without entering a password.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For login screen on gnome https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15628

For login screen on terminal shell:
Edit these files as per your need:

/etc/issue --> For console access (Login in text mode directly from the device), the messages stored in this file are displayed before the login line.

/etc/issue.net --> For remote access, via telnet or ssh, messages in this file are displayed before user login.

/etc/update-motd.d --> Messages from this will only be displayed after login

Comment: wont show python output but a static message